# Nexus 7 - Different Layouts for Portrait and Landscape modes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to show different layouts for portrait and landscape modes. The layout differs for all Nexus 7 - port / Nexus 7 -land / Nexus 10 - port / Nexus 10 - land.

Right now, i have the different layout showing from layout-large-land and layout-large-port.

I tried by creating layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw600dp-port (based on the developer's [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)) and placing the layouts over here. But, seems like the layouts are being fetched from layout-large-land and layout-large-port.

How do i specify separate layouts for Nexus 7 land and port as well as different layouts for Nexus 10 land and port.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout-xlarge-land and layout-xlarge-port for nexus 10. By large it means 7 inch and so nexus 7 will take from large.

layout-xlarge-land  landscape for 10 inch tablets

layout-xlarge-port portrait for 10 inch tablets

layout-large-land landscape for 7 to 10 inch tablets

layout-large-port portrait for 7 to 10 inch tablets

Comment: Ok, i tried this approach. Now when i open the application in Portrait(single view), then shift to landscape(when i have a detail view) and again rotate to Portrait, it crashes(saying it can't find the detail view). Any idea on how to solve it?